# Extension unresponsive even after restarting Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I recently ported a userscript as a chrome extension, and it works very well... until it doesn't.

This is the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rgtavcruises-extension/bnmgigkjikbelbgpflbgedefjiaolfbe

Code is on github in case anyone wants to inspect (the bulk of the code is on extension/js/events.js): https://github.com/yogensia/rGTAV_Cruises_Extension

So the problem is it has crashed 2 times in the last few days, but when it crashes it crashes for good. **Restarting chrome doesn't help, disabling/reenabling doesn't help either. Only removing it and reinstalling which instantly fixes it.**

While crashed, the extension is completely unresponsive:

- The popup doesn't open, if I click the button, I can see it toggle and remain pressed but the popup is not there.
- The badge doesn't update anymore.
- The options dialogue only loads the titlebar — my options.html code is not loaded.
- Trying to inspect the popup doesn't do anything.
- Inspecting the background process from the extensions menu opens the devtools window, but all tabs are completely empty. No resources or HTML loaded whatsoever.
- In the process explorer the extension uses around 25mb and 12% CPU (only when crashed).

Looking at the local files of the extension I didn't see any modified files or changes.

I have no idea how to debug or trace the issue. I haven't found any relevant info searching here or google, most results are about chrome issues and not about extensions.

Any help, feedback or ideas would be welcome. Thanks!

**Update:** After getting the issue to happen today, I started trying everything I could think of, and I've found that removing the local storage files from my Chrome profile folder fixed the issue, so I'm pretty sure now the problem is related to localstorage somehow.

Comment: you need to spend more time modifying the code, adding logs, debugging. we cant help debug your entire project without  specifics.

Comment: I'm not asking for that, I'm mostly hoping someone knows what could cause this behavior (since I assume it's not everyday that an extension just refuses to do anything without error messages of any kind) and can point me in the right direction. I'm just providing as much detail as I can.

Comment: you need to provide more specific detail. you likely have memory leaks. the question is too broad, would require someone to install the entire project and debug it.

Comment: By crashing, do you mean a real crash (aw snap, browser dies, or extension process is killed)? If so, are you using Windows 10 by any chance? I've seen a crash report for 64-bits Win 10 (which was not reproducible on Linux). To get more information, look at chrome://crashes to find a crash ID and/or see https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug

Comment: @ZigMandel Thank for the info any way, i'm not asking for someone to fix it for me, just for pointer and you already gave me one with the memory leak theory.

Comment: @RobW No, in my case there isn't any actual crash message or error of any kind, at least that I've seen. It's just the extension silently dying and not responding until reinstall. I'm on Windows 7 64bit btw and using Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit). Thanks for the link I'll see if they help in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was indeed caused by **localStorage** as I mentioned in the previous update. So I switched to using **chrome.storage.local** instead. Haven't had an issue in days since the change so it seems to be fixed now.

I see a lot of extensions heavily rely on **localStorage** without errors so I don't know exactly why it was happening (some Chrome bug somewhere maybe?) but at least It's fine now.

<sup>Source: [Yogensia edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37906663/3).</sup>